# How do I get 3 stars in level 2-12?

Tags: angry-birds

I am trying to get 3 stars in all `Angry Birds` levels, but now I am stuck with 2 stars at Level 1-2-12. I tried for more than hour, without success.

[image]

Does exists a place where I can find video or hints how to get 3 stars in every level? It would be nice also known which is the score I need to reach to get that stars.

Comment: It's quite heavily based on luck.

Comment: Not sure it's all about luck. Sometimes while looking to get the 3 stars I discovered new modes to finish a level.

Comment: @GnomeSlice research was done to prove that there is no random chance involved, I can't remember where it was though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always found 3-Star runs for every level i was in trouble with. Try searching for "Angry Birds Level X-Y 3 Star" on youtube if you have trouble with the X-Y level.

Comment: I had luck and finally I did it, similarly to what is shown in posted video link. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Rovio has an official [YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/RovioMobile) where they post the solutions to every level.  Typically, they post them is sets of 5.

Comment: Unfortunately those solutions don't always score three stars.

Answer (score -2):

I've only been able to get 2 stars on that level, but it is best to hit from above because it's weak there.

Comment: Generally, rolling back edits others have made isn't going to help you.  We're trying to make your content clearer, and more concise.  That's to your, and the site's, benefit.